# Analisar se um número é par ou ímpar

Tags: c, c++, lógica, c++11

O programa deve fazer:

> ```
> Digite um Número: 12345 
>
> 1 e ímpar  
> 2 e par  
> 3 e ímpar  
> 4 e pra  
> 5 e ímpar
> ```

Até agora eu fiz o seguinte código:

```
void parImpar (int num) {      
    int resto;
    while (num > 0) {
        resto = num%10;
        if(resto%2==0) {
            printf("\n%d eh Par", resto);
        } else {
            printf("\n%d eh Impar", resto);
        }
        num = num / 10;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int num;
    printf("Digite um numero inteiro: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    parImpar(num);        
}
```

Esse código me retorna o inverso:

> ```
> Digite um Número: 12345 
>
> 5 e ímpar  
> 4 e par  
> 3 e ímpar  
> 2 e pra  
> 1 e ímpar
> ```

Comment: Não está claro. A ideia é verificar número por número de um número? Exemplo: `255 | 2, 5 e 5`?

Comment: @Renan exatamente isso, Renan!

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Também não entendo de C++, Leo! Mas parece mais complicado do que aparenta ser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem algumas formas de fazer isso, tem a mais confusa e a mais inteligente, que eu preferi:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void parImpar (int num) {
    int digitos = floor(log10(abs(num))) + 1;
    for (int i = digitos - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int div = num / (int)pow(10, i);
        num = num % (int)pow(10, i);
        printf(div % 2 == 0 ? "\n%d eh Par" : "\n%d eh Impar", div);
    }
}

int main() {
    int num;
    printf("Digite um numero inteiro: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    parImpar(num);        
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/AcsNWy). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rxhtvges-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/OddEven.c).

Primeiro ele descobre o número de dígitos através de uma fórmula conhecida. Tem outras formas de obter isto, mas não gosto de nenhuma.

Aí fazemos um laço já sabendo onde começa e onde termina. E nele fazemos a conta para obter o valor do dígito dividindo pela potência de 10 elevando à posição que está analisando. E depois pega-se o resto dessa divisão para continuar fazendo o mesmo com os demais dígitos.

Exemplificando: a primeira potência resultará em 10000 (10 ^ 4) então dividir 12345 por 10000 dá 1 e isso é pode ser analisado se é par ou impar. Aí pega-se o resto disto que dá 2345 e que será dividido por 1000, então dá 2, e depois sobre 345 dividido por 100 que dá 3, e sobra 45 dividido por 10 dá 4 e finalmente 5 dividido por 1 dá 5.

Comment: Fantástico! Era exatamente isso! Obrigado pela explicação!